# ejs won't render Html page

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

I'm using Express with EJS to render the response from a database query as an simple Html page.
in dev tools shows an error

> "Access to fetch at
> 'https://o189131.ingest.sentry.io/api/5478725/envelope/?sentry_key=504fcb6b9eee411d8157d41c0adb1170&sentry_version=7'
> from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy:
> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
> resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's
> mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled."

And it doesn't render Html page, I want to use keep the extension of ejs file like home.html instead of using home.ejs.html in visual studio but I cant, why?

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.render('home')
})
app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log("LISTENING ON PORT 3000")
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a CORS error, which happens when your request is blocked by your browsers' same-origin policy. Try adding 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "*"' to your request header to bypass it:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
     res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
     res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
     next();
 });
```

You can read more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Origin).

Comment: Can you [edit] your answer to explain what did you changed and how this should fix the issue ?